# Golang - Sending API POST Request - Not enough arguments error

Tags: api, rest, go

The following code attempts to send a POST API request with a payload that is in RequestDetails.FormData. When I run main.go function, then I get the following errors.

```
go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:53:17: not enough arguments in call to http.HandleFunc
./main.go:53:33: not enough arguments in call to reqDetails.Send
        have ()
        want (http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
./main.go:53:33: reqDetails.Send() used as value
```

The code is available below. Anybody knows what I could do wrong here? Thanks a lot for your help.

```
//main.go

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// RequestDetails contains input data for Send
type RequestDetails struct {
    EndPoint string
    FormType string
    FormData map[string]string
}

// Send sends API POST request to an endpoint
func (rd RequestDetails) Send(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    json_data, err := json.Marshal(rd.FormData)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(rd.EndPoint, rd.FormType, bytes.NewBuffer(json_data))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)

}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "AuthParamOne":   "AP0000001",
        "AuthParamTwo":   "AP0000002",
        "AuthParamThree": "AP0000003",
    }

    reqDetails := RequestDetails{
        EndPoint: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        FormType: "application/json",
        FormData: m,
    }

    http.HandleFunc(reqDetails.Send())
}
```

Comment: There are two problems: (1) The call to `http.HandleFunc` is missing the string path argument. (2) Use `reqDetails.Send` as  the second `http.HandlerFunc` argument.  Do not call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Send method, you don't make use of w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, So it seems you don't need them:

```
func (rd RequestDetails) Send() {...
```

Also in your last line, HandleFunc requires different arguments which once again is not necessary in your case. Just try to run the Send method:

```
reqDetails.Send()
```

The whole main.go file:

```
//main.go

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// RequestDetails contains input data for Send
type RequestDetails struct {
    EndPoint string
    FormType string
    FormData map[string]string
}

// Send sends API POST request to an endpoint
func (rd RequestDetails) Send() {

    json_data, err := json.Marshal(rd.FormData)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(rd.EndPoint, rd.FormType, bytes.NewBuffer(json_data))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)

}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "AuthParamOne":   "AP0000001",
        "AuthParamTwo":   "AP0000002",
        "AuthParamThree": "AP0000003",
    }

    reqDetails := RequestDetails{
        EndPoint: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        FormType: "application/json",
        FormData: m,
    }

    reqDetails.Send()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use HandleFunc in following below:

```
func HandleFunc(pattern string, handler func(ResponseWriter, *Request))
```

for code above follow this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/test",reqDetails.Send) //-> add reference instead of calling 'reqDetails.Send()'
```

reference: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandleFunc

please vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

if your code like this

```
watcher := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
input, _ := watcher.ReadString()    
fmt.Println(input)
```

you needed this for reading line line

```
old -> input, _ := watcher.ReadString()   
new -> input, _ := watcher.ReadString('\n')
```